# Tensorflow gpu was working but is not working anymore error- Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: python, cuda

So I have cuda 10 installed along with tensorflow gpu 1.13.1 and everything was working just fine until I imported a VGG16 model. After running the model once and everything working just fine, when trying to run another model in keras i got this error.

Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
     [[{{node loss/mul}}]]

Now every time I try running any model in keras I get the same error.

Comment: This is a recurring problem I get. Sometimes restarting the computer can fix the problem.